# Como agrupar en un objeto información de 2 arreglos de objetos en javascript?

Tags: javascript, array, nodejs, algoritmos, objeto

Estoy realizando una actividad en la cual me dan 3 arreglos (vendedores, productos y ventas), son los siguientes:

```js
const vendedores = [
  { id: 1, name: "Juan" },
  { id: 2, name: "Carlos" },
  { id: 3, name: "Fede" },
  { id: 4, name: "Matias" },
];

const productos = [
  { id: 1, credencial: "132254524", name: "televisores" },
  { id: 2, credencial: "143618668", name: "estufas" },
  { id: 3, credencial: "78903228", name: "celulares" },
  { id: 4, credencial: "176812737", name: "Audio" },
  { id: 5, credencial: "216352696", name: "heladeras" },
];

//arreglo de objetos que contiene el id del producto vendido, el id de su vendedor y la cantidad
const ventas = [
  { productosId: 2,  vendedorId: 1, cantidad: 1200 },
  { productosId: 1,  vendedorId: 4,  cantidad: 500 },
  { productosId: 5,  vendedorId: 2,  cantidad: 20000 },
  { productosId: 2,  vendedorId: 3,  cantidad: 8401},
  { productosId: 3,  vendedorId: 1,  cantidad: 2877 },
  { productosId: 3,  vendedorId: 2,  cantidad: 1736 },
  { productosId: 2,  vendedorId: 3,  cantidad: 2965 },
  { productosId: 4,  vendedorId: 4,  cantidad: 1651 },
  { productosId: 5,  vendedorId: 1,  cantidad: 700 },
  { productosId: 1,  vendedorId: 1,  cantidad: 7956 },
  ];
```

En base a eso mi objetivo es crear un objeto con informacion de los arreglos, el cual: la key sea el vendedor y el value sea un arreglo con las credenciales de los productos que vendio

```js
 //Deberia quedar asi: 
      const objetivo={
      Juan: ["78903228","143618668","216352696", "132254524"],
      Carlos: ["216352696","78903228"],
      Fede: [ "143618668","143618668"],
      Matias: [ "132254524", "176812737"]
      }
```

Intente realizarlo de esta manera con un reduce pero esta mal, y no se me ocurre como sacar esa info y poder hacerlo. Desde ya muchas gracias y estoy abierto a respuestas y observaciones

```js
 function CreandoObjeto() {
          const objeto = ventas.reduce((acc, elem) => {
            acc= acc[elem.vendedorId]= elem.productosId
          }, {});
          return objeto;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La vía más fácil y directa (no la más eficiente) es recorrer cada venta, obteniendo su vendedor específico y el producto:

```
const result = ventas.reduce((acumulador, venta) => {
    const vendedor = vendedores.find(vendedor => vendedor.id === venta.vendedorId);
    const producto = productos.find(producto => producto.id === venta.productosId);
    
    if(!acumulador[vendedor.name]){
        acumulador[vendedor.name] = [];
    }

    acumulador[vendedor.name].push(producto.credencial);
    return acumulador;

},{})

console.log(result)
```

**¿Que problema tiene esta vía?**

Que por cada una de las ventas, vas a necesitar recorrer el arreglo vendedores y el arreglo producto, por tanto se hace un poco ineficiente.

---

**¿Qué alternativa tienes?**

Pues mapear los vendedores por id y los productos productos por id una sola vez y luego el acceso a ellos es directo. Por ejemplo:

```
const vendedoresPorId = vendedores.reduce((acumulador, vendedor) => {
    acumulador[vendedor.id] = vendedor;
    return acumulador;
}, {});

const productosPorId = productos.reduce((acumulador, producto) => {
    acumulador[producto.id] = producto;
    return acumulador;
}, {});


const result = ventas.reduce((acumulador, venta) => {
    const vendedor = vendedoresPorId[venta.vendedorId];
    const producto = productosPorId[venta.productosId];
    
    if(!acumulador[vendedor.name]){
        acumulador[vendedor.name] = [];
    }

    acumulador[vendedor.name].push(producto.credencial);
    return acumulador;

},{})
```

De cualquier manera, elije la que más te guste. A fines prácticos, los objetos deben ser INMENSOS para que la complejidad computacional sea un problema.

---

Si necesitas ordenar el arreglo de resultados usando algún tipo de criterio la cosa cambia, porque con el objetivo de tener la información de ordenación, el mapeo debe ser algo diferente. Te adjunto un ejemplo donde el arreglo de credenciales se ordena dependiendo del orden de sus `id`. Ten en cuenta que eso no fue especificado en tu pregunta inicial:

```
const result = ventas.reduce((acumulador, venta) => {
    const vendedor = vendedores.find(vendedor => vendedor.id === venta.vendedorId);
    const producto = productos.find(producto => producto.id === venta.productosId);
    
    if(!acumulador[vendedor.name]){
        acumulador[vendedor.name] = [];
    }

    acumulador[vendedor.name].push(producto);
    return acumulador;

},{})

for (const vendedor in result) {
    result[vendedor].sort((a,b) => a.id - b.id);
    result[vendedor] = result[vendedor].map(producto => producto.credencial);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me fue de mucha ayuda, tengo una consulta mas en base a como lo resolviste. Si quisiera que el arreglo de credenciales este ordenado dependiendo del orden de sus id, como deberia plantearlo

Comment: @mundoanillas ahí agregué cómo ordenarlo. No lo había implementado porque nunca lo especificaste en tu pregunta.